# php/mysql tags query schema

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a 3 table tag system, topics, tags and tagtopic.

I now want to display the various tags for each topic as I display the topic. Since there are multiple tags for one topic, when I do the query below, I get multiple rows and the topic displays multiple times, once for each row.  I don't think I can use a groupby as I'm not doing anything mathematical with  the columns.  What I really would like would be for each topic, display the topic and then a list of tags for a post such as (for Siri), 'iphone,smartphone,Siri'. 
tables:

```
topics
id | name |userid
tags
id | topicid | topicname
tagtopic
id | tagid | topicid '

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `topics` t
LEFT JOIN `tagtopic` tagtopic
on t.id = tagtopic.topicid
WHERE t.id= '12'";
```

Should mention that display is done with `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))` so that it is displaying the rows of the recordset.  I would like it to display the topic once, but since there are multiple rows created for the tags, it is displaying multiple times.

Do I have to give up on the join and do a subquery?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: please post tables structures.

Comment: Should `tags.topicname` instead be called `tags.tagname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) which will put all the tags into a single field separated by a comma.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tt.tagid) FROM topics t
JOIN tagtopic tt ON tt.topicid = t.topicid
WHERE t.id=12
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this query for ON AND ONLY ON topic ( deducted by `WHERE t.id = 12` )
In your `while` loop :

```
var first = true;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    if(first) {
        // PRINT THE TOPIC NAME
        $first = false;
    }
    // PRINT THE TAG ROW
}
```